# Euler's Theorem and Rectangles

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, rectangles

A rectangle is divided into smaller rectangles, whose sides are parallel with the big rectangle. Let $x$ be how many intersections there are (a point in the interior where $4$ rectangles meet), $y$ the number of rectangles, and $z$ the number of lines in the interior of the figure.

An example would be below, where $x=2, y=7, z=4.$

[image]

Find an expression for the number of rectangles in terms of $x$ and $z.$

So far, I know that each internal line defines $2$ rectangles, and an intersection defines $4$ rectangles. I think we can proceed with Euler's Formula $(V+F=E-2)$ or $E \leq 3V-6.$ However, I'm not sure on how to find the number of edges or vertices.

How would I continue from here?

Comment: Any ideas? I'm pretty stumped still.

Comment: $V+F=E+2 $ on 3D solids.

Comment: Then what Identity can I use, or how can I proceed. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You start with 1 rectangle. Every time you draw a line without creating an intersection, you turn one rectangle into two. If you decide to create an intersection by extending the line further, you split another rectangle in two. So every line and every intersection creates one new rectangle, and the number of rectangles you get is $1+z+x$.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thank you!

Comment: @JaapScherphuis please consider turning your comment into an answer, so that it can be accepted by OP.